# are multiple elements in a node of a doubly linked list possible?

Tags: c

I was wondering if its possible to  insert multiple elements in a node of a doubly linked list in C. I need this to be able to read in a file with contents such as:

00:00   67.7

00:01   67.6

00:02   67.7

00:03   67.6

00:04   67.6

00:05   67.3

00:06   67.4

and copy the first 4 numbers as 2 integers and the third as a float. i was hoping to put those 3 in a node of a doubly linked list to later on be able to compare them to numbers in other nodes. i was thinking of something along the lines of this:

```
while (fscanf(ifp, "%d:%d %d.%d ", &hour, &min, &tempI, &tempD) != EOF) {

int dlist_ins_next(Dlist *list, DlistElmt *element1, *element2, *element3, const void *int1, *int2, *float);
}
```

Comment: what is stopping you in this. just create a node which has two int and 1 float. put this in struct with the next and prev pointers.

Comment: This has to be somewhat related to [Creating doubly-linked list from text file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765713/creating-doubly-linked-list-from-text-file-on-c), though the user ID is different (but the sample data is organized the same, and the (mis)use of two integers to read a floating point number is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted the third as a float value, change your scan function to :

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d:%d %f ", &hour, &min, &temp)
```

And you should be implementing the node as a structure :

```
struct node
{
  int hour;
  int min;
  float temp;

  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;    
};
```